# Hazelcast Serialization nested objects

Tags: java, performance, serialization, hazelcast

Hello I am having one question in regards of the latest Hazecast versions and serialization. Lets have the following class:

```
class Customer implements DataSerializeable {
    List<Address> adresses;
    CustomerDetails details;
}
```

Both classes Address and CustomerDetails implement DataSerializeable. The way we are serializing them at the moment is:

```
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
   out.writeObject(address);
   out.writeObject(details);
}
```

In some examples online I saw that the way they are serializing the same class is:

```
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
   address.writeData(out);
   short size = details.size();
   out.writeShort(size);
   for (CustomerDetail detail: details) {
      detail.writeData(out);
   }

}
```

I ran some performance test over couple of milion records I was not able to observe significant difference in performance.

What is the recommended way to do serialization of the Nested Objects. Can someone comment on that with regards of the latest Hazelcast version 3.6.

Thank you

Comment: There's a line missing from the last example, where the size gets written out before the details. Beyond that, your first code snippet does Collection-specific  serialization, the last one does Collection-type-agnostic. If you have f.e. lazy lists from hibernate you don't want to serialize the list object, but the elements.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I would like to know is there any noticeable difference when it comes to performance. My impression is that while out.writeObject() is called the Hazelcast is looking up overtime the serializer that should be used in contrast to the example number 2. Can we say that there can be a noticeable difference in performance, or we are talking about negligible difference. In my case we are not using lazy collections. Should we go with example one or example two. Thank you.

Comment: Go with #1 if you want to preserve the implementation type of the collection, otherwise go with #2; the performance should be very slightly better (but it's likely lost in the I/O noise, and why aren't you setting up a test to try it with your own data profile?).

Comment: I have stated in the above comment that i have setted up a test and IT did not measure difference in performance but my PC has just 8gb of ram. I was not sure if on larger scale the results will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days there is no noticeable difference since we have optimized serializers for ArrayList, LinkedList, HashMap. That way you get the almost same benefit as handwriting it.

The ArrayList serializer classes can be found here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/serialization/impl/ArrayListStreamSerializer.java

Looking at the code you'll see, that it'll give you almost the same benefit.